# Word-wrap of Label text in text-area

Tags: html, css, forms

I want to re-size the label of a text-area in the format shown in the picture below. I'm trying to do a wrap using a paragraph tag, but it is not working.

My code:

```
 <label for="qual">This is the format i want the text-area to be displayed:</label>  
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <textarea id="qual" rows="5" cols="50" style="resize:none" placeholder="Description and Qualification"></textarea><br><br>
```

Desired Output:

[image: image of a box with a text label to the left, where each line of the label is wrapped to a new line after one or two words, so that the label is the same height as the box]

Answer (score 17):

Try `white-space: normal;`

For more details visit
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Answer (score 14):

```
style="max-width: 140px; word-wrap: break-word"
```

place these styles in your label tag and adjust the max-width or min-width to your needs.

This doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Answer (score 7):

Here is a [JSFiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/CRMhf/1/).

The HTML:

```
<label for="qual" class="abc">This is the format i want the text-area to be displayed:</label>
<textarea id="qual" rows="5" cols="50" style="resize:none" placeholder="Description and Qualification"></textarea>
```

The CSS:

```
.abc{float:left; width:125px; text-align:left; margin-right:30px;}
```

If you don't want to create a class, you can apply the styles on `label` in the CSS.

Comment: You don't need to declare `display: inline` because it will be computed to block because the element is floated.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

Comment: Yes. I saw the specification. Point taken. Updated the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/CRMhf/1/ - @MarcAudet

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
label { 
  float: left; 
  width:120px;
  padding:10px 30px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jwB2Y/1/)

Comment: how can i place this label on the left hand side of the textarea??

Comment: thanks it works!!!will it work on screens of different sizes like 13 inch,20 inch and 24 inch screen without changing it's position from the left hand side of the text area??I want to use it in a form so i want the form elements to have fixed position with respect to one another...

Answer (score 1):

In the  block of your HTML add:

```
<style>
  label { padding:5px; font-weight:bold; float:left; width:150px; }
</style>
```

The style settings above will also replace the   spacing:

```
<label for="qual">This is the format i want the text-area to be displayed:</label>  
<textarea id="qual" rows="5" cols="50" style="resize:none" placeholder="Description and Qualification"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to style the `label` and `textarea` elements in a self-contained, bullet-proof manner.

I suggest the following HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <label for="qual">This is the format...to be displayed:</label>
    <textarea id="qual" rows="5" cols="50" style="resize:none" 
              placeholder="Description and Qualification"></textarea>
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
.wrap {
    outline: 1px dotted blue; /* Just for demonstration... */
    overflow: auto;
}

.wrap label {
    outline: 1px dashed blue;
    float:left;
    width: 10em;
    margin-right: 1.00em;
}
```

Define a parent container `div.wrap` to hold the two child elements and specify `overflow: auto` to generate a new block formatting context.

You want to do this to make sure that the floated label field does not interfere with any other adjacent elements that may be in the page or form.  This may be important if you are building a responsive design.

The `<label>` field is floated left and you must specify a suitable width. You can also apply margins, background color or images, padding as needed to create the design that you need.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/2sTez/

Comment: how can i place this label on the left hand side of the textarea??

Comment: I updated the fiddle/demo with a second example demonstrating a flexible design.  The widths for the label and the textarea elements scale with respect to the width of the parent element.  You can see the effects by varying the window width.

Comment: Regarding 13/20/24 inch screens, the results will vary depending on the overall width of your page.  However, the flexible version (example 2) will work over a wide range of window sizes.  You may want to specify a `min-width` or `max-width` value depending on your overall design.